# Am I using Entity framework v4.0?

Tags: .net, entity-framework-4

Evey sample code for entity framework wihch I find on the net are telling that there must be a method "ApplyChanges" which I can use to persist SelfTracking objects. But my ObjectContext and EntitySets just have these methods:

1. ApplyCurrentValues
2. ApplyOriginalValues

Am I using EF4? Is there any minor versions of EF4?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [MSDN entry here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff407090.aspx) explains that ApplyChanges is an extension method generated by the ADO.NET Self-Tracking Entity Generator in Visual Studio 2010 and later. If you're not generating those methods, you won't see them, even if you are using EF 4/.NET 4.0.